# trying to center divs within another div using inline css

Tags: html, css, inline-styles

I have an assignment for class (I know inline CSS isn't standard practice) in which he wants us to specifically use inline css in order to have a div box containing three other boxes that are centred horizontally. When I try to do it, no matter what I try, the formatting ends up odd, and I can't make them show up horizontally next to each other.

[Here's what I tried:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IL11.png)

[Here's what it looks like, sorry for the badly scribbled out personal information.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2RBw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the assignment very well, but I came up this:

```html
  <h2>Using Float</h2>
  <div style="background-color: pink; padding: 20px; text-align: center; display: flow-root">
    <div style="background-color: aquamarine; margin-right: 20px; width: calc((100% - 40px) / 3); height: auto; float: left;"><p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p></div>
    <div style="background-color: aquamarine; margin-right: 20px; width: calc((100% - 40px) / 3); height: auto; float: left;"><p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p></div>
    <div style="background-color: aquamarine; margin-right: 0px; width: calc((100% - 40px) / 3); height: auto; float: left;"><p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p></div>
  </div>
  <h2>Using Flex</h2>
  <div style="background-color: pink; padding: 20px; text-align: center; display: flex; gap: 20px;">
    <div style="background-color: aquamarine; flex-grow: 1;"><p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p></div>
    <div style="background-color: aquamarine; flex-grow: 1;"><p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p></div>
    <div style="background-color: aquamarine; flex-grow: 1;"><p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p></div>
  </div>
  <h2>Using Grid</h2>
  <div style="background-color: pink; padding: 20px; text-align: center; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr; gap: 20px;">
    <div style="background-color: aquamarine;"><p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p></div>
    <div style="background-color: aquamarine;"><p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p></div>
    <div style="background-color: aquamarine;"><p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p></div>
  </div>
```

In the **Float** example I use `width: calc((100% - 40px) / 3)` instead of `width: 33%` in order to eliminate the `margin-right` of the child divs (`20px + 20px + 0 = 40px`). If that makes sense...
I also use `display: flow-root` on the container div, which is the easiest and safest way to create a [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context).
Hope it helps.